# Is there a suitable Stack Exchange site to ask this question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked a question on [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), *[Signing into Google account refreshes already open webpage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/57110/signing-into-google-account-refreshes-already-open-webpage)*:

> I have noticed that signing into my Gmail account, automatically
>   causes some webpage to refresh. For example, signing into Gmail while
>   keeping
>   http://poetsandquants.com/2014/01/10/the-spaceship-enterprise-comes-to-yale/
>   open in another tab causes the page to refresh once signin/out is
>   done.
>
> - How is this done?    * I am guessing this is some sort of tracking
>     mechanism. Is this a known "feature" and legal?

The feedback I got was that it wasn't suited for that site. Is there a place where I can ask it? Two places I have in mind are Stack Overflow and [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com)?
What can I do?

Comment: the only guy to answer your question is google.

Comment: [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) comes to mind.